# When specifying mean and tolerance, is the use of plural counters determined by the mean or the tolerance?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

An object is angled 6 degrees. No problem.
An object is angled 1 degree. Again, no problem.
Through a series of tests, an object was angled 6 ± 2 degrees. Still, no problem.

What about:
Through a series of tests, an object was angled 6 ± 1 degrees.  -OR-
Through a series of tests, an object was angled 6 ± 1 degree.

Is plurality based on the mean (6) or the tolerance (1)?

Comment: Hm, the answer is affected by the notation. If it were spelled out it would be more clear-cut: "... was angled 6 degrees, plus or minus 1 degree."

Comment: Just to stir the pot, what if it were 1.002 degree(s)? or 0.999 degree(s)?

Comment: "6 ± 1 degree" sounds better to me, because it's really just shorthand for saying "6 degrees plus or minus 1 degree" and then becomes @AndyBonner 's case.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Interesting. I was about to say "partial units are plural if > 1, singular if < 1" ("half a degree," "one and a half degrees"). But maybe that's only true for fractions; I feel like decimals would still take plural for < 1 ("0.75 degrees")...

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Singular grammar is for the integer 1. Any number other than the integer 1 is grammatically plural. Even 1.0 is plural.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty of course we wouldn't state the uncertainty to more precision than the mean, would we?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the plural, for a few reasons.

First though, in my  writing (physics), I'd get round the issue with "object was angled 6 ± 1°" (`6&nbsp;&pm;&nbsp;1&deg;` in html).

If however you want to use words, I'd use the plural, because the end result is plural, lying in the range from 5 to 7 degrees (and of course we'd use the plural for fractions or decimals in that range).  I suggest it should be parsed as *(mean ± uncertainty) units* rather than *mean ± (uncertainty units)*.  While this is from a logical or scientific point of view, I reckon the use of language should follow that, and the mean ± uncertainty part would take the plural unless exactly 1.  We'd also say "...was tilted through an angle of *n* degree**s**, where *n* was initially 6 ± 1").

The [SI Brochure](https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) is what
I normally refer to for questions on specifying units.  It's not as helpful in this case as it normally is, as it doesn't say much about names .

Section 5.3 begins

> Unit names are normally printed in upright type and *they are treated like ordinary nouns*. [emphasis mine]

(Note that the SI guide prefers a different notation for uncertainty, at least when expressed with unit symbols rather than names)

Comment: I also felt that it should be plural for your reason: (mean ± uncertainty) units rather than mean ± (uncertainty units).